# VBScript passing an array into SSRS VB code

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript, reportingservices-2005

Within SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services I am attempting to evaluate an expression which outputs an array which I attempt to pass to my VBScript code with my report.
My parameter values are 
BU
MC
CD
DU

The join function correctly outputs the string `BU-MC-CD-DU`
I then use the split function within an expression to split the values and output as an array as such

```
 =Split(join(Parameters!ReportType.Value,"-"),"-",-1,1)
```

After which I then pass the array to my VBScript code within the report using the expression below within a textbox :

```
=Code.debugReportVisible(Split(join(Parameters!ReportType.Value,"-"),"-",-1,1))
```

My VBScript function is as follows

```
function debugReportVisible(pSelectedReports() ) as String
  dim debug as String
  debug = CStr(pSelectedReports(0))
end function
```

The code does not error but no value is displayed in the textbox.. Can someone tell me why this is?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Just to be superfluous, but you are using `option explicit`, did not use `on error resume next` and you did including a `MsgBox debug` in your last function, didn't you?

Comment: Thanks Automated, I dont think its a data issue. The issue seems to be passing the array from the expression to the VB-Script function defined in the report's code. Given that I simply passed the string output from the join expression to the VB-Script function then split it in the code there and it worked. Though still not sure why the code above doesnt work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up just passing the the hypen (-) seperated string to the 'isReportVisible function' from my join expression defined for the hidden property of each subreport (for e.g the BU sub report visibility hidden expression is as below)

```
=Code.isReportVisible(join(Parameters!ReportType.Value,"-"),"BU")  

function isReportVisible(pSelectedReports as String, pSubReport as String) as Boolean
      dim hidden as Boolean
      dim reportArray
      dim counter
      hidden = true
      counter = 0
      reportArray= Split(pSelectedReports,"-")
      for counter = 0 to UBound(reportArray)
      If reportArray(counter) = pSubReport Then
      hidden = false
      End If
    Next
      return hidden 
    end function
```

Hope this helps someone....